# How to add images Onenote Interop

Tags: c#, .net, interop, office-interop, onenote

i'm a young sysadmin and want to write a little tool for my colleagues who use the microsoft surface.

The Onenote Cloud Version can access the webcam and insert the pictures directly into a notebook.

Outlook 2010, 2013 and 2016 don't have this feature.

So i started to write an add-in. I can already access the webcam and save pictures but i have problems adding the picture to a notebook.

I am using the Office.Interop dll but i don't really know where to start.

I hope you can help me.

Thank You.

Edit :

This is a part of the code :

```
   private void GetNameSpace()
    {
        MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
        pictureBoxVideo.BackgroundImage.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        string fileString = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray());


        string xml;


        string thisPage = oneNoteApp.Windows.CurrentWindow.CurrentPageId;


        oneNoteApp.GetPageContent(thisPage, out xml,PageInfo.piAll,XMLSchema.xs2010);
        var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        string toAdd = @"<one:Image>
                <one:Data>" + fileString + @"</one:Data>
            </one:Image>";

    }
```

Now i have to use UpdatePageContent but how exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new page, and add an image to it via UpdatePageContent. You will need to create a new XML and update.